# Margin for select option in IE and chrome is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am setting a css class to some select options in JS. This class includes margin style. It is working in the FF but not in IE and chrome.

```
 window.onload = function() {
    replace('edit-field-region-tid');
    replace('edit-tid');
}
function replace(id) {
    var i = 0;
    var s = document.getElementById(id);
    for (i; i < s.options.length; i++) {
        if (find(s.options[i].text, id, i)) {
            s.options[i].setAttribute("class", "sub_options");
        }
    }
}
function find(str, id, option_id) {
    var i;
    var s = document.getElementById(id);
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == '-') {
            s.options[option_id].text = str.cutAt(0, "");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
String.prototype.cutAt = function(index, char) {
        return this.substr(index+1, this.length);
}
```

And CSS:

```
.sub_options{
    margin-left:20px;
    text-indent:-2px;
}
```

Any ideas thanks!

[image: FireFox]

[image: Chrome]

Comment: Can you show error messages ?

Comment: Can you post the html code also and error console?

Comment: how is t not working? perhaps create a fiddle or attach a screen shot

Comment: I have attached screenshot. I also wondering why it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way: http://jsbin.com/oyatis/1/edit

```
$('select option').prepend('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
```

I tried using css method of jquery but that is not getting affected, but some non-breaking spaces are valid ways to move the elements. See if this works for you.

Comment: I have change s.options[i].setAttribute("class", "sub_options"); line to $(s.options[i]).prepend('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'); and it is working perfecty. Thanks JaiPSah.